# How to fix ZeroDivisionError while using uncertainties package?

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero, uncertainty

I have two `unumpy` arrays:

```
A= [390.9999999999952+/-19.77371993328507
 129.99999999999932+/-11.40175425099135
 34.99999999999997+/-5.9160797830996135
 4.999999999999999+/-2.2360679774997894 0.0+/-0 0.0+/-0
 4.999999999999999+/-2.2360679774997894]
B= [33.999999999999964+/-5.830951894845297
 17.33333333333334+/-4.163331998932266
 9.666666666666666+/-3.1091263510296048
 4.999999999999999+/-2.2360679774997894 0.0+/-nan 0.0+/-nan
 4.999999999999999+/-2.2360679774997894]
```

I would like to propagate their errors while calculating the error in the mean ratio through:

```
fraction = np.where(unumpy.nominal_values(A) > 0, unumpy.std_devs(B/A), np.nan)
```

But I do not know how to fix the following error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code4.py", line 2076, in <module>
    fraction =            np.where(unumpy.nominal_values(A) > 0, unumpy.std_devs(B/A), np.nan)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uncertainties/core.py", line 661, in f_with_affine_output
    f_nominal_value = f(*args_values, **kwargs)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: This error comes when you are dividing something with 0. Like 10/0, 5/0. It just indicates that, somewhere in your code, a calculation took place and the denominator where is zero. Recheck every variable value again, and remove everything whose value is 0...

Comment: Hey Abhay, thank you for the response. But, zeros are meaningful in the sense that I want to have empty "right" position in the array when I am plotting this as an errorbar. Absence of value in any position of this array should mean a lack of errorbar. But, the position of this empty bin is not known for each case, I would like to track them as NANs if possible as I am showing only a single run of the code. Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Comment: How would you wish the output be when B is nan and A is 0.0 and vice versa? I am not fully sure if I understand your desired output. Maybe you can have a desired sample output for your input so we can help better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by the following changes in the line above:
What I did was basically propagating the error through the division of two values where errors in the two parameters are added in quadrature from first principle.

```
fraction = np.where(unumpy.nominal_values(B) * unumpy.nominal_values(A) > 0, (unumpy.nominal_values(B)/unumpy.nominal_values(A)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square([unumpy.std_devs(B)/unumpy.nominal_values(B), unumpy.std_devs(A)/unumpy.nominal_values(A)]), axis=0)), 0.)
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` has physical significance for sure. But for computation, Computer Science can't handle `NaN` or `Inf` as they are indefinite. So usually how we handle this mathematical error by adding a small value. Which will not have much impact.

Usually in many mathematical libraries they handle like below;

lets say we have matrix/vector `A` which can contain 0. and I am going to divide by another matrix. So before that we can do below preprocessing.

```
import sys
eps = sys.float_info.epsilon

A+=eps
```

This will add a very small value like `2.220446049250313e-16` to all the elements. so by doing this your distribution of matrix will be retained either.

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: Apart from this you have some tolerance that also `+/-nan` this you have to make then `0`. As indefinite tolerance will not help for any computation as its indefinite.

Answer (score 1):

Replace any zeros with some value epsilon **(*i.e*: 1e-9 or 1e-7)** `A.clip(1e-9)`

```
fraction = np.where(unumpy.nominal_values(A) > 0, unumpy.std_devs(B/A.clip(1e-9)), np.nan)
```